# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named ws-persist

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jersey, jax-rs

I'm building a JAX-RS web service (Jersey) and now I'm trying to start using JPA. I have selected eclipselink to manage this persistence.

To start off, I'm writing some junit test cases until I figure out how everything will come together.

In my persistence.xml (WEB-INF/persistence.xml) I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
<persistence-unit name="ws-persist" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>beans.Change</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3333/tomcat" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="tomcat" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="...." />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

In my test class I have.

```
public class PersistenceTests {

private EntityManager em = null;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {      
    Properties propertiesMap = new Properties();
    propertiesMap.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.DDL_GENERATION, PersistenceUnitProperties.DROP_AND_CREATE);

    EntityManagerFactory  factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ws-persist", propertiesMap);
    em = factory.createEntityManager();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void testSetUp(){
    Assert.assertNotNull("Entity manager was null", em);
    Assert.assertTrue("Entity manager wasn't connected", em.isOpen());
}
}
```

I have eclipselink.jar, and two javax.persistence_*.jars under my WEB-INF/lib folder.
I'm getting the exception metioned in the title, can someone please help me figure out how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: seems like it cannot find the provider, ensure the eclipselink.jar is on your classpath correctly.

Comment: When I look at my buildpath under "web app libraries", eclipselink.jar is listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to add the persistence provider in the persistence.xml

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

(**edit**) or moving persistence.xml to `META-INF` folder. For a web-app this has to be in `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: I think i had that in there before - this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: This is a web app, I tried it in both locations and it didn't work.

Comment: this works if i create a META-INF folder under my src folder and put persistence.xml in that. Is there something I'm missing as to why it isn't working in any other location? Is the classpath incorrect?

Comment: I believe by placing it in source it gets copied to WEB-INF/classes (classpath in Tomcat) in your final build.